# Calling all Javascript API experts ---Embedded Tableau multiple views using Tableau Javascript Api in order to implement filter on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tableau-api

I am currently embedding multiple views on a webpage utilizing Tableau Javascript API. Since I have 5 different views to embed, I am pulling 5 URLs and do getElementById 5 times to pull those.

How to simplify this?

```
            var viz;

    window.onload=function ()
    {




        var vizDiv = document.getElementById('myViz0');
        var vizDiv1 = document.getElementById('myViz1');
        var vizDiv2 = document.getElementById('myViz2');
        var vizDiv3 = document.getElementById('myViz3');
        var vizDiv4 = document.getElementById('myViz4');



        var vizURL = 'https://blahserver/@Model.TableauTrustedTicket/views/Workbook/blah?:render=false&';
        var vizURL1 = 'https://blahserver/views/Workbook/Blah1?:render=false&';
        var vizURL2 = 'https://blahserver/views/Workbook/Blah2?:render=false&';
        var vizURL3 = 'https://blahserver/views/Workbook/Blah3?:render=false&';
        var vizURL4 = 'https://blahserver/views/Workbook/Blah4?:render=false&';




        var options = {
            width: '1000px',
            height: '800px',
            hideToolbar: true,
            hideTabs: true

        };


        viz0 = new tableau.Viz(vizDiv, vizURL, options);
        viz1 = new tableau.Viz(vizDiv1, vizURL1, options);
        viz2 = new tableau.Viz(vizDiv2, vizURL2, options);
        viz3 = new tableau.Viz(vizDiv3, vizURL3, options);
        viz4 = new tableau.Viz(vizDiv4, vizURL4, options);


    }; //LoadTableau Ends here


    </script>
```

Applying Filter Here after the vizs have been loaded on the page. As you can see I literally copies each for loop which applies to one view to loop it through 5 URLs so that filters can work. I know it is not the efficient but I am open to any suggestions. Thank you!

```
 vizFilter2: function (filterValue) {


        sheet = viz1.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();

        worksheetsArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for (var i = 0; i < worksheetsArray.length; i++) {

            worksheetsArray[i].applyFilterAsync("FilterName", filterValue, tableauSoftware.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE)

        }

        sheet = viz0.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();

        worksheetsArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for (var i = 0; i < worksheetsArray.length; i++) {

            worksheetsArray[i].applyFilterAsync("FilterName", filterValue, tableauSoftware.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE)

        }
        sheet = viz2.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();

        worksheetsArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for (var i = 0; i < worksheetsArray.length; i++) {

            worksheetsArray[i].applyFilterAsync("FilterName", filterValue, tableauSoftware.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE)

        }
        sheet = viz3.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();

        worksheetsArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for (var i = 0; i < worksheetsArray.length; i++) {

            worksheetsArray[i].applyFilterAsync("FilterName", filterValue, tableauSoftware.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE)

        }

        sheet = viz4.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();

        worksheetsArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
        for (var i = 0; i < worksheetsArray.length; i++) {

            worksheetsArray[i].applyFilterAsync("FilterName", filterValue, tableauSoftware.SelectionUpdateType.REPLACE)

        }

    },
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have the freedom to modify the workbooks. If you do have that option, then I would recommend that you shared filters across all sheets in a workbook. If you do that, you won't have to iterate through `worksheetsArray` and fire `applyFilterAsync` on each sheet. You just need to `applyFilterAsync` on 1st sheet in a viz.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much control over the workbooks. However, do you suggest any method to simplify this loop?